# Best way to build a steps wizard with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wizard

I need to build a wizard :
5 steps , in each step - different form.
Here's a picture which discribes the wizard:
[steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqMhK.png)

I'm wondering whats the best structure to implement this.
Each step ofcourse has its own controller,directive,template. 
How can i connect between the Wizard and the Steps?
(At the end I need to submit all the form data I've received from the user),
Also - Whenever the user finish a step - we need to update the steps module .

Answer (score 0):

So for this situation, there are two possible solutions.

1) The Wizard should be a controller with each step would being a directive. The each directive can handle the logic for each step without affecting the workflow.

Directives have two way data binding like any other component in angular. So you can watch variables or call back functions from directive to controller.

Controller <-- data binding --> Directive

The advantage is that everything is broken up into modules and you can treat this as a multipart form.

The downside is that it will managing updates to multiple files.

2) The second solution would be to move the business logic for each step into a service. Controller will only need to call the service to validate and update the form when needed.

```
app.service('WizardService', function(){
   this.step1= function(a,b) {
      //logic here
      return false;
   }
   this.step2= function(a,b) {
      //logic here
      return false;
   }
   this.whatsNextStep= function() {
      //logic here
      return stepN;
   }

});
```

Ideally with you should put your business logic in a service or factory to prevent code duplication and overall good practice.

Hope this helps.